# How do I change the Animation of a LineSeries? LiveChart.Wpf

Tags: livecharts

I have several `LineSeries` which are displayed in a `CartesionChart`.
The Series is created in the Code behind and filled in a `SeriesCollection`. 
Everything works fine it is displayed correctly.
The Problem is the Animation, first the points "fly" in from the left and then the line "flies" in from the left. 
Sorry but that looks really strange to me.

I would already be happy if the points and lines would fly in together or if both would "fly" in from the bottom.

I just found in the documentation that I can disable all animation, that looks really boring. And [here](https://lvcharts.net/App/documentation/beta/wpf/LiveCharts-Wpf-Charts-Base-Chart) at the `AnimationSpeed` property description, it says I can change that for the elements within. I could also make the Animation very fast. But I was unable to find the option in the elements within (`LineSeries`). `LineSeries` or `Series` in general do not have an AnimationSpeed property.

Every help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @mrid No I had to disable the animations :(